# Clickatell error in sending Multi-part Non English SMSs using Kannel gateway

Tags: http, sms, kannel, clickatell

I am trying to send multi-part SMS in Arabic (UTF-8) format using Clickatell Operator, I am unable to, 1 part Arabic SMS works fine, multi-part English SMSs also work fine, just the multi-part Arabic SMSs don't.

These are my configurations:

```
group = smsc
smsc-id = clickatell
smsc = http
system-id = ******
system-type = clickatell
smsc-username = ******
smsc-password = ******
send-url = "http://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg"
port = 13015
allowed-smsc-id = clickatell
connect-allow-ip = "127.0.0.1;192.168.100.*;196.30.96.134"
log-file = "/var/log/kannel/clickatell/clickatell.log"
log-level = 0
```

AND, my sendsms configurations:

```
group = sendsms-user
username = ***
password = ***
concatenation = true
max-messages = 7
```

Any help or thoughts would be nice, thanks.

Comment: Hi Amin,
I would like to help you but I need more details in order to understand the problem. First, what version of Kannel are you using? Can you please post what Kannel logs in /var/log/kannel/clickatell/clickatell.log when you're sending multi-part Arabic SMS ? Also, what are the parameters for the HTTP GET request to the sendsms interface?